# open PDF and save with a string inside - python

Tags: python, pdf

I have a lot of pdf files in folder and I need to rename all files with a value in first row.
For example I have a file abccabbccabcb.pdf and in first row I have a value XXXXXXX I need to rename my file with XXXXXXX.pdf
Is it possible to do with Python?

Thank you for your support
Angelo

Comment: "in first row I have a value": What row?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can read PDF files using a library called PyPDF2, it's possible to rename python files using a built in file function.

You could possibly write a small automation script where if it finds value x in the first row, it automatically changes the name

I found most of this information from a web page on realpython.com
You could check there as well
https://realpython.com/creating-modifying-pdf/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello Aviation6, it works! Thank you :)